# Ajax - How to create a Category through actionTrigger

Tags: categories, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to create a jQuery/Ajax script to import data from a Wordpress API service and want to import the WP categories and tags into my database. I've managed to import the tags using an Ajax call to `/actions/tags/createTag`, is there any endpoint that does the same with categories?

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is, otherwise we would not be able to store categories in Craft. The controller that handles categories is called `CategoriesController` and it contains the function `actionSaveCategory` so you route will be `actions/categories/saveCategory`

To create/save a user you have the `UsersController`.. You may guess the function is `actionSaveUser` => `actions/users/saveUser`

It's the same for every element in Craft. `EntriesController`, `actionSaveEntry` => `actions/entries/saveEntry`

But this all has nothing to do with an endpoint or an API, it's just basic Craft code